# Missing wrapper in XML

Tags: python, xml, pandas

I'm trying to pull specific data from one big XML to another. My Main XML File looks like below

```
<MAIN>
<transaction>
        <date>20190415</date>
        <ticket>1</ticket>
        <value>15</value>
</transaction>
<transaction>
        <date>20190415</date>
        <ticket>2</ticket>
        <value>15</value>
</transaction>
<transaction>
        <date>20190415</date>
        <ticket>3</ticket>
        <value>15</value>
</transaction>
<transaction>
        <date>20190415</date>
        <ticket>4</ticket>
        <value>15</value>
</transaction>
<transaction>
        <date>20190415</date>
        <ticket>5</ticket>
        <value>15</value>
</transaction>
</MAIN>
```

I'm only pulling the `<ticket>` values & Appending it to a Fresh/New xml file.

Below is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from lxml import etree

path_source = 'source\path'
path_dest =  'dest\path'

tree = ET.parse(path_source)
root = tree.getroot()

L_roots = []

for trx in root.iter('transaction'):
    ticket = trx.find('ticket').text

    root_T = ET.Element('MAIN')
    doc = ET.SubElement(root_T, 'Transaction')

    ET.SubElement(doc, 'ticket').text = ticket

    L_roots.append(doc)

with open(path_dest,'wb') as f:
    for i in L_roots:
        ET.Element('MAIN')
        f.write(ET.tostring(i, method="xml"))
```

what i get is a plain text file without the outer `<MAIN>` tags. like below

```
<Transaction>
    <ticket>1</ticket>
</Transaction>
<Transaction>
    <ticket>2</ticket>
</Transaction>
<Transaction>
    <ticket>3</ticket>
</Transaction>
<Transaction>
    <ticket>4</ticket>
</Transaction>
<Transaction>
    <ticket>5</ticket>
</Transaction>
```

What is missing here is the wrapper `<MAIN>` tags. what should be changed in my code to achieve this?

Comment: Where does pandas come in in the question (why the pandas tag)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:

```
with open(path_dest,'wb') as f:
    for i in L_roots:
        ET.Element('MAIN')
        f.write(ET.tostring(i, method="xml"))
```

with this:

```
outroot = ET.Element('MAIN')
outroot.extend(L_roots)

with open(path_dest,'wb') as f:
    f.write(ET.tostring(outroot, method="xml"))
```

The error in your snippet is that you never save the new `ET.Element('MAIN')` to a variable, so that is lost. When using `f.write` you are simply writing the elements in `L_roots`, which have the Transaction tag.

In the snippet I propose, all the `L_roots` elements are inserted into another MAIN element, and then the main element is written (all its subelements are automatically written).